# TSQL: Executing a stored procedure inside a BEGIN...END block

Tags: sql, t-sql

When calling a stored procedure outside of a BEGIN...END block, I don't need to use the EXEC or EXECUTE command; the following works:

```
SP_RENAME '[dbo].[TableName].[old_column]', 'new_column', 'COLUMN'
```

However, when I move this line inside a BEGIN...END block, it will throw a synatx error unless I use the EXEC or EXECUTE command:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'old_column' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TableName'))
BEGIN
    EXEC SP_RENAME '[dbo].[TableName].[old_column]', 'new_column', 'COLUMN'
END
```

Any reason why?

Comment: I think you only do not need an exec statement if the statement is the first statement in a batch... eg ... GO SP_REName ...; When it's in a loop it's not the first statement and thus must be exec'd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MSDN's `EXECUTE` Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258848%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> You do not have to specify the EXECUTE keyword when executing stored
>   procedures if the statement is the first one in a batch.

Therefore, your second example throws the error because the stored procedure call is not the first statement in the batch.